# Запустить скрипт из другого скрипта

Tags: html, perl

Есть три кнопки. Две из них вызывают один скрипт, третья - другой.

```
<p>
<form method="POST" action="script1.cgi">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка1">
<input type="hidden"...>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="script2.cgi">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка2">
<input type="hidden"...>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="script1.cgi">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка3">
<input type="hidden"...>
</form>
</p>
```

Не катит. Во первых подобный код вообще противоречит правилам. И потом, помимо того, что <form> начинается с новой строки(margins:0 и т.п. - не помогает), самое главное почему то <input type="hidden" ...=""> перестают что либо передавать. Поэтому сделал так:

```
<form method="POST" action="script1.cgi">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка1">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка2">
<input type="submit"  name="Кнопка3">
<input type="hidden"...>
</form>
```

И встала задача:

На входе скрипта функция обработки STDIN и условия:

```
if ($in{'Кнопка1'} ne "") {...}
elsif ($in{'Кнопка2'} ne "") {  И вот как здесь выполнить script2.cgi с передачей POST-параметров ему? К тому же, открываться результат должен в новом окне  }
elsif ($in{'Кнопка3'} ne "") {...}
```

Может быть как то по другому можно решить сию задачу? Главное, что бы все кнопки распологались в один ряд и работали "хиддены".
Спасибо!

Comment: И как на этом сайте сделать что бы пример кода форматировался по человечески? А то каша какая то

Comment: Подправил форматирование. Нажмите "править", чтобы посмотреть, как это выглядит "внутри".

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Таки задачу я решил, если кому интересно, вот каким образом:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="Кнопка1" / onClick="this.form.action = 'script1.cgi';this.form.target='_self'">
<input type="submit" name="Кнопка2" / onClick="this.form.action = 'script2.cgi';this.form.target='preview'">
<input type="submit" name="Кнопка3" / onClick="this.form.action = 'script1.cgi';this.form.target='_self'">
</form>
```

Т.е. `elsif ($in{'Кнопка2'} ne "")` {...` убрал за ненадобностью. Чисто на HTML.

Всем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #forms form {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
....
<div id="forms">
    <form method="POST" action="script1.cgi">
        <input type="submit" name="Кнопка1" />
        <input type="hidden" value="..." />
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="script2.cgi">
        <input type="submit" name="Кнопка2" />
        <input type="hidden" value="..." />
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="script1.cgi">
        <input type="submit" name="Кнопка3" />
        <input type="hidden" value="..." />
    </form>
</div>
```